# How to nest a struct into another struct when they're defined in separate files?

Tags: c, struct, nested, embedded, header-files

I've searched for the answer to this, but its hard to find anything because the question is hard to phrase.

Lets say we have file1.h which defines a struct:

```
//file1.h 

struct foo{
    int param1;
    ...
};
```

Later I want to incorporate this foo struct  into a general struct bar defined in a different file:

```
//file2.h
#include "file1.h"

struct bar{
    struct foo foo1;
    int param
    ...
}
```

I want it to be the same struct definition such that I dont have to modify two structs with the same parameters, and I dont want to use pointers since I have some serialization like routines that operate on bar. Also, I want foo to be defined in file1.h so I dont have to define it elsewhere every time I use the functions of file1. Is this possible, and is this even a good idea?

(I'm trying to achieve modularity where file1.c can be used either by itself or directly tied into the code in file2 without having to redefine structs everywhere)

Comment: I'm going to edit this to say #include "file1.h" in file2 so that people dont think thats the mistake lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very much possible and it is used everywhere.

```
//file2.h

#include "file1.h"

struct bar {
    struct foo foo;
    int param;
    ...
};
```

The `#include` directive tells the preprocessor to dump all contents of file1.h into file2.h.

And this is what you've been doing all along. You type `#include <stdio.h>` in order to grab the declerations of functions like `printf`, `scanf`. Naturally this works for structures, types and other things. You can even share variables if you do it correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not at work right now so I can't check again, but it didnt seem to work when I did it (though it did allow me to include pointers to the struct.) That said, its good to know that it was supposed to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a couple of adjustments.

```
//file2.h

#include "file1.h" // <===================== include file here

struct bar {
    struct foo var_foo; // <================ fix syntax here
    int param
};
```

You will access the fields of `struct foo` embedded in `struct bar` as follows:

```
#include "file2.h"

int main() {
    struct bar var_bar;        
    var_bar.var_foo.param1 = 0;
}
```

Comment: You are also correct, I apologize for my sloppy example. The problem is that it wasn't working with the correct syntax and as result I wasn't sure if it was possible at all. I just wanted to know if it was possible. I'll edit my question some more.